# JavaFX: Right click on TableColumn disables resizing

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, openjfx

Reproduced in OpenJFX 11.0.2 & 12.0.1 SDK (Windows 10, x64), not reproducible in JavaFX 8

Right-click on a table-column, then try to resize the column. No resize cursor is shown and column can't be resized until you manually click on the column again.

Any ideas for a workaround? I need to use`contextMenu` for TableColumns, so potential workarounds that make the header ignore right mouse click aren't possible.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Foo extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Object> testView = new TableView<>();
        testView.getColumns().addAll(new TableColumn<Object, Object>("C1"), new TableColumn<Object, Object>("C2"), new TableColumn<Object, Object>("C3"));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(testView));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this using JavaFX 11.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I’m surprised that program runs at all in Java 12, since JavaFX is no longer part of Java SE.  A subclass of javafx.application.Application can no longer be a Java main class, because the native libraries required by JavaFX are not available at the time the JVM starts the main class.

Comment: @VGR That's not true so long as the JavaFX modules are on the modulepath—at least, I've never had a problem (even when omitting the `main(String[])` method).

Comment: I _can_ reproduce the problem using JavaFX 12.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Slaw You are correct.  I should have clarified that my statement only holds true when using a classpath rather than a module path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the following (very, very dirty) workaround. I never tried this before because I assumend it would prevent the context menu from showing (as I noted in my original question), but apprently simply consuming the mouse event of every `TableColumnHeader` works and the context menu is still shown correctly (also works with TableColumns without context menus).

Not sure if anything internal could go wrong with this, but as the right click doesn't seem to be doing anything useful by default, I hope not.

Of course `lookupAll` needs to be called after it has been rendered.

**Note 1:** If you have `TableMenuButtonVisible` set to true, you need to do this every time a column is set to visible.

**Note 2:** Its getting dirtier and dirtier. Simply calling this again after a column has been set to visible (see note 1) doesn't **always** suffice (also not with a `Platform.runLater` call). I assume that's because the column header hasn't been rendered at that point. You either

- need to wait until the `Set<Node>` is fully filled, i.e. the size of
  it must be `amountOfVisibleColumns + 1`. If its equal to the amount
  of visible columns, it won't work for the newly shown column.
- or call `layout()` on the TableView before `lookupAll`
- or if you have a class that extends `TableView`, override `layoutChildren` and execute the lookup if the amount of visible columns has changed

**Note 3**: You need to keep track of the old `onMousePressed` and execute it if the button isn't `SECONDARY`, otherwise the reordering of columns won't work.

Please let me know if you can think of any cleaner way.

[image]

```
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Foo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Object> testView = new TableView<>();
        testView.getColumns().addAll(createColumn("C1"), createColumn("C2"), createColumn("C3"));

        stage.setOnShown(ev -> {
            Set<Node> headers = testView.lookupAll("TableColumnHeader");
            for (Node header : headers) {
                if (header != null) {
                    ((TableColumnHeader) header).setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                            e.consume();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(testView));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<Object, Object> createColumn(String text) {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Context");
        item.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("Action");
        });

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.getItems().add(item);

        TableColumn<Object, Object> column = new TableColumn<>(text);
        column.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        return column;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If one doesn't already exist, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: see my answer below :-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Found the described bug in the Java bug tracker and filed a PR with the fix:

https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/483

EDIT 2: My PR was accepted and merged back. The bug is fixed now, you can test it by using 17-ea+11. :-)

I have the same problem. This bug is caused by the `mousePressedHandler` added in `TableColumnHeader`. This class has even more problems, for example if I close a `PopupControl` with `setConsumeAutoHidingEvents(true)` by a click on a column, the sorting will be triggered. Those methods needs to be changed, maybe the `addEventHandler` methods should be used instead of the convenience `setOn...` methods.

I fixed it by consuming the event when I'm about to show my `PopupControl`:

```
public class MyTableColumnHeader extends TableColumnHeader {

    public MyTableColumnHeader(TableColumnBase tc) {
        super(tc);
        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, this::onMousePressed);
    }

    private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            showPopup();
            // Consume here, so the column won't get 'stuck'.
            mouseEvent.consume();
        }
    }

    private void showPopup() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Eventually, someone should open at least a bug. I may will also have a look in the not too distant future.